# TypeError in using React app with jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-plugins

I created an app with react-create-app command and i use the react 16. i want to use katrik-v fileinput (a jquery plugin) too. that is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Cell }  from 'react-foundation';
import Header from './Heaader';
import $, { jQuery } from 'jquery';

class New extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
    $(document).find('#root').find('#test-upload').fileinput();
}


render(){
    return (
        <div>
          <Grid type="x">
               <Cell medium={2} large={2} >
                    <label htmlFor="image" className="text-right middle">
                           <p className="form-label">Images</p></label>
               </Cell>
               <Cell medium={8} large={8}>
                    <div className="file-loading">
                        <input id="test-upload" ref='fff' type="file" 
                        multiple />
                    </div>
               </Cell>
         </Grid>
      </div>)
}
}
export default New;
```

When I call it in the index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm facing this error:

> TypeError:
>   __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_jquery___default(...)(...).find(...).find(...).fileinput
>   is not a function.
>            $(document).find('#root').find('#test-upload').fileinput()

what is the problem?
In general, how can these two be merged?(a jquery plugin and react app)

Comment: Include jQuery and its plugin in your app's `public/index.html` using standard `<script>` tags. Then replace the line that imports jQuery with `/* global $ */`.

Comment: In the index.html everything is right. Should I change this line?(import $ from ''jquery''). What should I replace?

Comment: Replace `import $, { jQuery } from 'jquery';` with `/* global $ */`

Comment: Thanks @Chris, i'm amateur. please explain what this line does?

Comment: It allows you to use the `$` object from your `<script>` inside your React code. Did it work?

Comment: Yes it worked, does it not interfere with other js files?

Comment: No; the other JS files are bundled when you build the app. No interference I can see.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance @Chris

Comment: You're welcome; added it as answer; would appreciate it if you accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use jQuery plugins with React apps, you should pull jQuery out of the webpack process.

Include jQuery and the plugins as static files or via CDN using `<script>` tags in your `public/index.html`.

To use jQuery in your React files, add

```
/* global $ */
```

to your class files as if it were an import line.